# Typescript - return an empty array without declaring a local variable

Tags: typescript

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
let emptyArray: string[]
    if (context == null) 
        return emptyArray
```

Is there no way to do this:

```
    if (context == null) 
        return new string[]
```

Comment: By the way, be aware of that you in the first example are returning `undefined` since you do not initialize emptyArray. In the other example, it looks like you want to return an empty array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also type assert what you return so that the compiler knows that you are returning a `string[]` and not just an array. If you don't want to define it anywhere else.

```
if (context == null) 
    return [] as string[];
```

And of course, an empty array is always a valid value for any kind of array.

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely clear what you want because there's no context, for example who returns the empty array and who's getting this result, but it's easy to just do:

```
function fn(context: any): string[] {
    if (context == null) {
        return [];
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but this seems to be valid typescript for me in my editor:

```
getValue(context): Array<String> {
    if(context==null) {
      return [];
    }
}
```